# Java: Where does Maven store system properties set in the pom.xml within a compiled jar?

Tags: plugins, maven, compiler-construction, pom.xml, system-properties

We've specified a bunch of system properties in our maven compiler plugin definition within pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>

                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <key>aKey</key>
                        <value>aValue</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
             <!-- ....etcetera.... -->
```

These are automatically loaded when the jar is executed

How does Maven create this auto-load behaviour for system properties? I'd like to understand the practical implementation of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is not behaviour I would expect (unless I am misunderstanding you). Compile-time system properties should not be persisted at runtime.

I created a basic maven project that just prints out the system properties and it did not contain the system property specified in plugin configuration.

`System.getProperties().getProperty("aKey")` returned `null` at runtime even with compiler plugin configured the same as yours.

Any other plugins running that might have an effect? How are you accessing the system properties?

Comment: We're fairly sure it does persist because we have a project with a property specified as per my example and the code sees it as set to `true` upon execution of the jar. Searching the project - indeed grepping it - reveals no additional instances of the keyword. The environment we deploy to does not have it defined in any loaded project files.